# Blender 2D move the view

Tags: 2d

I try to find shortcout to moving view in my 2D project. Actualy I use virtual button on interface[image],

and i tried use **shift+MMB** but it doesnt works. Where in preferences can I select this shortcut? In 2D animation there is no **move the view** options[image]

Comment: Should be the same for all views. Under Preferences > Keymaps > Name search, type 'image.view_pan' (without the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

In the keymap edition, it's called *Pan View* <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> is the standard shortcut. You should consider mapping middle mouse button to one of your pen tablet button.

If it doesn't work it could be that you're using a track pad. In that case, in the *Blender Preferences*, go to *Input* tab and activate *Emulate 3 Button Mouse*. By doing this you'll be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> to pan.

When you're using greasing pencil you're in 3d view not 2d view

Comment: adrien There's no mention of Grease pencil in the original question.